# Multi-select Lookup Field data to VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Ultimately I'm going to want to make a whole bunch of checkboxes enabled&unlocked/disabled&locked based on which values are checked in a multi-select lookup, and how many are allowed. To do this, first I need to know how to get at the data in these multi-select lookups through vba. I imagine.

I've tried to set a variable in vba to the value of one of these fields, but the only data type it seems to accept is `variant` - and even then I can't get the immediate window to tell me what I've collected into that variable.

I need vba to be able to work out if a certain label is one of the ones listed in the multi-select field.

---

Now for further explanation/context, real examples: Lets say you can pick colours for a book based on what author and genre the book "owns". Each author and genre has a variable number of colours you can pick, and a limited range.

Lets say the book is by Bob, who is allowed an 2 of red, blue, orange and yellow, and it's a fantasy book, which can be 3 of red, white, grey, black and purple.

All of the checkboxes on the form for red, blue, yellow, orange, white, grey, black and purple become enabled and unlocked, while all the rest remain locked and disabled as they aren't available at all.

- The user selects red - no change, except for that box being selected.
- The user also selects blue - no change, except for that box being
  selected, because while 2 (max allowed) of bob's colours are
  selected, red is also on the fantasy list, which still has 2
  remaining. The overlap saves more.
- The user de-selects red, and selects yellow - red is still available
  (fantasy) but orange is now disabled and locked.
- The user selects red, white and purple - grey and black are disabled
  and locked, as all options have now been exhausted.

Now, if you want to start me on all of how that'll work, fantastic, but all I'm really asking at this point is how to get hold of the data in those multi-select fields. The rest is for context etc.

Comment: That's a _lot_ of background information for an on-topic and simple question. It might be better received if you remove or trim it, and add a line of code showing what doesn't work (are you trying to access the field using a recordset, or a bound control?)

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by *multi-select lookup*?

Comment: @Andre: A lookup field where the options you select in the lookup wizard (the only way I know of to create lookup fields in a table) run as: I want the lookup field to get the values from another table or query > Table: tbl1 > Field1 > Order By Field1 > Hide Key column > Allow Multiple Values. (obviously where tbl1 and Field1 are whatever table/fields you select.) The key here is that when you don't select "Allow Multiple Values" the data is easily retrievable in VBA. When you do, it doesn't seem to cooperate...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: a bound control. The identifying fields (lets say AuthorName and GenreName) live in combo boxes. When the user selects the author and the Genre using those combo boxes, it automatically enables the corresponding colour checkboxes. With your answer I think I can make this happen, except for what's going to eventually be my next question - tweaking what I believe I can now put together coding wise to deal with overlap between author and genre in the business logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Value` property of a multi-select field, either a recordset or a control, is defined as a variant array in Access. This means you need to use array functions to get the value.

You can read the value like this:

```
rs.Fields("MyMultiValuedField").Value(0) 'First value
Join(rs.Fields("MyMultiValuedField").Value, ", ") 'Concatenated values
```

And set the value like this:

```
rs.Fields("MyMultiValuedField").Value = Array("Value1", "Value2")
```

Note that in a lookup field, the keys are stored, not the values being looked up. And in my experience, MVFs have minimal validation when assigning using VBA, you can even insert values of the wrong type leading to garbage.

Comment: Amazing! That answers my question, I think! Can I further clarify by asking if I want to look up the values that are pointed to there, if it would go something like `dim ColCh as string; For each value in tbl1.Fields("MultiField"); ColCh = ColCh + tbl2!Field1 where ID = value` is that even close to the syntax I'd be looking for? (";" replaces line break for the purposes of formatting unfriendly comments)

Comment: Assuming Value is an integer, that sounds about right. I don't get that WHERE there, though, and you need to add a Next to close the For Each loop. Note that if you're just concatenating values, you could ise the Join function instead of the loop, that both keeps your code shorter, and is more optimized

Comment: Could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207308/creating-an-array-in-vba-based-on-two-array-fields? That's where I've actually written some coding to try to make this happen...

Comment: Err... Are you using DLookUp to look up MVFs? That doesn't work.

Comment: Ech. What should I use then?

Comment: 'cause I need it to point to that specific record. LIke, I could do basically what I have here, but how do I make it *that* record if I can't use the where?

Comment: Just a recordset. CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("Select Field From Table Where Something").Fields(0).Value is the equivalent of DLookup("Field", "Table", "Something")

Comment: @Isaac Reefman, the `.Value` property of a multi-select field defined as `Recordset2` object data type and `Join` function fails with "Type mismatch" error. Did it really work for you?

Comment: @SergeyS. Oh, I confused the fields value, and the recordets value. If you write up an answer, I will delete this.