# Creating an array in VBA based on two array fields

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I have a couple tables with lookup fields that point to the same data in a third table, and both fields can select multiple values. A user can select a record from each table, and I need to be able to separate out the overlapping values in VBA.

To do this, I've tried creating a third array in VBA into which I'll dump the resulting values, but I'm getting a Type Mismatch error. I can't seem to find a reason that this would occur. The code, reduced as much as I can without losing the sense of it is below:

```
Function SetEnabledColours()
'Indexes for arrays of available colours
Dim IndA As Long, IndG As Long, IndO As Long
'Arrays of available colour options
Dim AuthorCol, GenreCol, OverlapCol()

AuthorCol = DLookup("[AllowedColours]", "tblAuthor", "[Author]= '" & cmbAuthor & "'")
GenreCol = DLookup("[AllowedColours]", "tblGenre", "[Genre]= '" & cmbGenre & "'")

'Separate overlapped options
'Cycle through AuthorCol
For IndA = LBound(AuthorCol) To UBound(AuthorCol)
```

[And then I get the Error]

```
    'Check each GenreCol against this AuthorCol
    For IndG = LBound(GenreCol) To UBound(GenreCol)
        If GenreCol(IndG) = AuthorCol(IndA) Then
            'Add to OverlapCol(CountO)
            ReDim Preserve OverlapCol(IndO)
            OverlapCol(IndO) = GenreCol(IndG)
            IndO = IndO + 1
            'Skip over to next AuthorCol
            GoTo Escape1
        End If
    Next IndG
Escape1:
Next IndA
```

Originally I had Dimmed the Indexes as integer, but I have since realised that this was because I was thinking of the arrays as ranges. I understand data of this type is stored as an array rather than a range.

Erik's answer here points me towards arrays: [Multi-select Lookup Field data to VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170258/multi-select-lookup-field-data-to-vba)

And this is what I'm basing my overlap array creation on: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28530517/remove-array-element-in-access-vba.html

Comment: DLookup doesn't create array, please read help about this function. So, all function won't work. Use recordsets instead. Whole code should be rewritten. And also `Dim IndA, IndG, IndO As Long` creates two variants (IndA, IndG) and one Long (IndO), not 3 Long variables.

Comment: One SQL query should solve your task.

Comment: @SergeyS. - Aaah. I did *not* know that. does that mean I can `Dim IndA as Long, IndG as Long, IndO as Long`?

As for DLookup creating an array, I was merely using DLookup to find the data stored in the AllowedColours lookup, in which multiple values can be selected. From my research (and asking on this site) I have been led to believe that this data is stored as an array.

Comment: Yes, data type should be indicated for each variable, default is Variant.

Comment: What I meant with that line of code was "Can I declare several variables in one line, without repeating the Dim keyword, and specify several different data types?"

Comment: As for DLookup creating an array, I was merely using DLookup to find the data stored in the AllowedColours lookup, in which multiple values can be selected. From my research (and asking on this site) I have been led to believe that this data is stored as an array.

Comment: Would `AuthorCol = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("Select AllowedColours From tblAuthor Where Author = '" & cmbAuthor & "'")` do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Also, considering the immediate window gives me a list of values separated by commas when I ask `?AuthorCol` with the current code above, does that mean DLookup is just giving me a string?

Comment: ... `AuthorCol = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("Select AllowedColours From tblAuthor Where Author = '" & cmbAuthor & "'").Fields(0).Value`, like I shared on the other post. Don't omit parts.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - I thought I was going to need to omit that part, as it looks like it's referring to a specific instance in AllowedColours. Is that not what the `(0)` indicates - the first value in the array?

Comment: Yes, you can declare variables in one row, separate by comma.  Recordset for field with multiple values returns another recordset with data type `Recordset2` and as far I know there is no automatic conversion to array, you need to cycle thru this secondary recordset and add values to array. Frankly I would recommend to avoid using fields with multiple values, manipulations with them quite complicated and this feature has some bugs.

Comment: It's the first field in the field collection. `Fields(0).Value(0)` refers to the first value in the array.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - gotcha. Thanks for that clarification. Still confused about why I'd need to specify the first field in the fields collection if I've already specified in my `SQL` that I'm selecting `AllowedColours` as a field in `tblAuthor` though.

Comment: Eh... A recordset always contains a field collection, and you can fetch multiple fields at once in a single recordset. That's just how it works.

Comment: @SergeyS. - Would you instead suggest I work with strings and add/remove bits, and do text based interrogations of them instead? If that's what you mean, to me it seems much messier...

Comment: Of course. Recordset. You can't open a single field, so that makes sense. I'll pick up the basics eventually. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: No, bits also not good solution. Using normal many-to-many database relation with 3 tables is a classic solution, you'll be able to extract all data very easy. But you will need to create a custom form for assigning multiple values to current record. BTW internal implementation of multiple value fields also uses two invisible service tables for each field

Comment: Wow. Can't believe that never occurred to me. Rebuilding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLookup for multiple values field returns a string with list of values separated by comma (and a space), so you should use the `Split` function for converting this string to an array:

```
AuthorCol = Split(DLookup("[AllowedColours]", "tblAuthor", "[Author]= 'd'"), ", ")
GenreCol = Split(DLookup("[AllowedColours]", "tblGenre", "[Genre]= '" & cmbGenre & "'"), ", ")
```

Comment: YES! This almost works: the first entry in the list is right, but every other one inherits the space in front of it from after the comma. Simply change the delimiter from "," to ", " and it works.